# Skip First Post in Every Page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, posts

I'm working with WordPress custom query, I want to skip the first post on every page i.e page 1,2,3 ...
I have a query but don't know how to skip only first post.

```
Suppose there are 19 posts id 1,2,3 ... 19,
I want 1st post having id 19 should be ignore on every page with posts_per_page => 6
So, on page 1 posts of these id's will be shown :  18,17,16,15,14,13 and
on page 2 posts of these id's will be shown :  12,11,10,9,8,7 and 
on page 3 posts of these id's will be shown :  6,5,4,3,2,1
```

Here we can see that first posts(id => 19) is being skip on every page, this is what I want, How I can achieve this?

**Query:-**

```
$catID = 13;
  $page = $_POST['page'];
  $output = '';
  $total_pages = 0;

    $args = [
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'cat' => $catID,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $page,
    ];

  $posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

**Note:** I used offset => 1 but this is not working as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add offset

```
    $catID = 13;
      $page = $_POST['page'];
      $output = '';
      $total_pages = 0;
    
        $args = [
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'cat' => $catID,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' => $page,
            'offset' => 1
        ];

  $posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: As I told above, I used this as well but in this way When I get to page 2 or 3 then same posts I'm getting, seems like pagination is not working

Comment: no problem, thanks for your time and effort